# what would a terlrik control method return if it doesnt find what it is looking for?

Tags: telerik

Example case:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-objects-radtreeview.html

in this example, what would be the return if   .findNodeByValue() didnt find a match?  null? 0? undefined?  Usually documentation would cover the slew of return results.  Maybe I am used to a more indepth plethora of information at my disposal, I dunno.

Comment: I suggest creating a simple test.

Comment: i know.  I just think that if people are designing something such as telerik, they should have a "returns" segment that tells it as well.  You shouldnt give partial documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing a simple:

```
 var tv = $find("TreeView");
```

then putting it into a browers console, you can do:

```
 tv.findNodeByValue("lolwhat");
```

which would return *null*.